# Why can't I get WatchConnectivity to work right? (Video demo)

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchconnectivity

WatchConnectivity seems to fail updating its reachable state when the watch is deactivated and reactivated rapidly (lowered and raised within a 1-2 second time span). This occurs reliably on my devices.

Edit: Here's a demonstration of the bug: https://youtu.be/hx7VR8IPxT8

And it's an Open Radar report #23337218

I've written a test project to get you the simplest possible example of the bug.

```
import UIKit
import WatchConnectivity

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, WCSessionDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    private let session: WCSession? = WCSession.isSupported() ? WCSession.defaultSession() : nil

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        session?.delegate = self;
        session?.activateSession()
        return true
    }
    func sessionReachabilityDidChange(session: WCSession) {
        print("Session \(session.reachable ? "reachable" : "not reachable")")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            //updates UI
        })
    }
}
```

And the watch extension

```
import WatchKit
import WatchConnectivity

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, WCSessionDelegate {
    private let session: WCSession? = WCSession.isSupported() ? WCSession.defaultSession() : nil

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        // Perform any final initialization of your application.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        session?.delegate = self;
        session?.activateSession()
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive() {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, etc.
    }

}
```

What happens when I lower the watch: Delegate calls sessionReachabilityDidChange in 1-2 seconds giving the correct state.

THEN
if I raise the watch after sessionReachabilityDidChange updates, the delegate gets called again as expected.

But if I raise the watch BEFORE sessionReachabilityDidChange updates, the delegate gets called just once, reflecting the NOT reachable state and fails to call again to reflect the correct active state of the watch app.

Here's a download to the project https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2649851/WatchConnectivityTest.zip

Edit: I should mention this doesn't seem to be a problem on the Simulator.

Comment: 2.0.1 Sorry, forgot to add that. 9.0.2 on iPhone.

Comment: Sounds and looks like a bug in the OS. Did you file a bug report with Apple?

Comment: Nope. I figured this was such an obvious bug, it must've been seen before. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Radar filed #23337218. I must be missing something critical here. This really screws up my app. D: